# ofstream odd behavior

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I've come across an odd behavior of the ofstream, 'least odd to me. Here's my program, i'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition.

```
int main () {

    std::ofstream file("file.txt");
    file << "something1";
    file.close();

    file.open("file.txt", std::ios::ate | std::ios::in );
    file << "something2";
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the correct output.

> something1something2

Now if i replace the 9th line with the following code,

```
file.open("file.txt", std::ios::ate);
```

i get this output.

> something2

But if i replace the 9th line again, this time with this code,

```
file.open("file.txt", std::ios::ate | std::ios::in );
```

i get this output.

> something1something2

Now, i guess the question is, could somebody help me out make any sense out of this? Why does the last solution work, but the middle one doesn't.

**EDIT:** Corrected the main function. You learn something every day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `ofstream` defaults to `std::ios::trunc` -- the flag to truncate the existing content.  Passing `std::ios::in` disables truncation (unless the `trunc` flag is also specified).

Actually, the rule is that `fstream` performs truncation if the `trunc` flag is used, or if the `out` flag is used and neither `in` nor `app` (notice `app` is different from `ate`, `app` repositions *every* write, while `ate` only affects the initial pointer).  `ofstream` automatically sets `out`.  `trunc` cannot be used without `out`.